# How to get device's IMEI number in android Version 10?

Tags: android, android-studio

I want to know, how to get device unique identification number from which i can identify android phone.
Before android 10 ,this use to get work.

```
TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
imeiNumber = tm.getDeviceId();
```

But In android 10 ,this is not working .
Can anyone suggest what should i do for android 10.

Comment: IMEI on Q+ is only available for system-level apps  https://developer.android.com/about/versions/10/privacy/changes#non-resettable-device-ids

Comment: Is there any other unique Id other than this ?